# HTML/CSS: How to vertical align image inside one of the div relative to another

Tags: html, css

How to vertical align image inside one of the div relative to another
Image size is unknown;
max-height:150px; max-width:150px;

First div contains the image
Second div contains the text

I want to make two floating divs the same height
and to vertical align image inside one of the div

Is it possible without tables?

Comment: Need more information.

Comment: use css style table-row / table-cell and then you can do vertical-align...but yes more information perhaps add the code

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=css+vertical+align

Comment: Display: table for the outer div, display: table-cell for the inner. vertical-align: middle for inner. IE8 and up :)